# blender default view setting

Tags: 3d-view

Nothing shows in my blender 2.8 beta when i open it.
Objects are there but the whole thing is dark unlike 2.79 version.

[image: 2.79 viewport]
[image: 2.8 beta viewport]

Comment: It shouldn't be this way, maybe a bug. Which build do you have? Have you tried downloading a more recent one?

Comment: I don't know the build. think ill keep to 2.79 for now

Comment: You can know the build by looking at the splashscreen: https://i.imgur.com/GzHLo3P.png (If you don't see the splash screen, hit the blender icon on the top left corner). There are even the date and the branch name. As you can see, mine is a little bit obsolete already.